# Scala: Better way to handle Future.Filter.exists without any specific conditions

Tags: scala, collections

Scala: I need to perform an action only if the previous future returned Some(x). what's a better way to do this than using below code

```
def tryThis: Future[Option[T]] = {...}

val filteredFuture = tryThis.filter(_.exists(_ => true))

def abc = filteredFuture.map( _ => {...})
```

Comment: Also note that `filter` will fail the Future (with a very generic exception), so that is most likely not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to call `map` on the `Option` like this:

```
tryThis.map(_.map(_ => {...}))
```

This will call the function only if the `Future` returns `Some(x)`. The result with be another `Future[Option[U]]` where `U` is the result of your function.

Note that this will return `Future(None)` if the the original `Option` was `None`, whereas `filter` will generate a failed exception, so they don't quite do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
def tryThis: Future[Option[T]] = {...}

// Resulting future will be failed if it a None
// and its type will be that of the expression in `x…`
def abc = tryThis collect { case Some(x) => x… }

// Resulting future will be a None if it was a None
// and a Some with the type of the expression in `x…`
def abc = tryThis map { _.map(x => x…) }
```

Comment: You should probably explain that your two solutions produce different results.

Comment: @Tim Good call—amended.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace:

```
tryThis.filter(_.exists(_ => true))
```

with:

```
tryThis.filter(_.isDefined)
```

Comment: Thanks for ```_.isDefined``` @senjin.hajrulahovic, 
how dumb of me to write this ```_.exists(_ => true)```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def square(a: Int): Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful(Option(a * a))
  def printResult(a: Int): Unit           = println(s"Result: $a")

  square(2).foreach(_.map(printResult))
```

EDIT: As per @Thilo suggestion

Comment: `foreach` or `andThen` seems more appropriate if there is no return value and only a side effect.